# UBUNTU 13.04 GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

A recent upgrade to SQL Developer 4.0 in Ubuntu 13.04 has generated an error.

gnome_desktop_session_id=this-is-deprecated

my current work around is to just run

```
$ unset gnome_desktop_session_id
```

After this I can run sql developer and everything works fine.

Any suggestions on how to fix this with out having to run the unset command every time?

Comment: Have you tried to copy-paste this code in your `~/.bashrc` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your system set it for you by putting this `unset` command to `/etc/profile` or in a `.sh` shell script that you place in `/etc/profile.d/`

If you launch SQL developper from console, you can also put the command in `.bashrc`

Comment: The solution that worked best for me was leaving it in the .bashrc file. This ENV appears to be set after the /etc/profile.d/ scripts are being ran.

Answer (score 5):

I modified /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
cd "`dirname $0`"/sqldeveloper/bin && bash sqldeveloper $*
```